# Reverse 10 last Objective-C Array objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using following code to reverse the objects in an array. but this methods reverse all the objects in array.

```
NSArray* finalreversed = [[myArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

How can I reverse only last 10 elements in array, i.e myArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split off the first (length-10) objects. Split off the last 10. Reverse the latter. Concatenate the former with the reversed.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUInteger rangeLength = MIN(10, myArray.count);
NSUInteger rangeLocation = MAX(0, myArray.count - rangeLength);
NSArray *lastTenReversed = [[[myArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeLocation, rangeLength)] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
NSArray *finalArray = [[myArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, rangeLocation)] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:lastTenReversed];
```

The `MIN`/`MAX` checks ensure that you don't go out of bounds. If the array has less than 10 objects, it will simply reverse all of them.

Comment: Thanks, but I did following next answer by Seva, Upvote for you Sir,